# Possible to append class to nav menu added to widget area?

Tags: menus, filters, navigation

I'm wondering if it's possible to add a menu class to a navigation menu added to a widget area? I realize that when adding a menu to a template via `wp_nav_menu` one can use the `menu_class` option to append a custom class to the menu's `<ul>` element, but I can find a way to do the same to a menu added to a widget area- perhaps via  filter? In my case, I need to add a class to trigger a menu script, and adding it via JS is creating issues, so I'd like to add it on the PHP side if possible. Thanks for any insight here!

Comment: Did you try just targeting a more specific class identifier?  `.footer .nav_menu ul` ? (or whatever structure your theme is providing)

Comment: Yes, it's an annoying combination of factors- theme, script that runs the responsive menu, etc.- and it would be much easier if I could just add a class to the menu markup itself when the menu is generated.